# iTextSharp - Adicionar imagem TIFF num PDF

Tags: c#, imagem, itextsharp, imagemagick

Estou a usar as bibliotecas Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU versão 7.12.0 e o iTextSharp.

Primeiro abro a imagem com o Magick e guardo essa página do TIFF numa pasta. Depois uso essa imagem para adicioná-la no PDF.

Estive a fazer alterações no código e deixou de funcionar. E já tentei usar um código que eu sabia que estava correto e mesmo assim dá-me este erro:

> System.ArgumentException: Extra samples are not supported.
>
> at iTextSharp.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.GetTiffImageColor(TIFFDirectory dir, RandomAccessFileOrArray s)
>     at iTextSharp.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.GetTiffImage(RandomAccessFileOrArray s, Int32 page, Boolean direct)
>    at iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Uri url)
>     at iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(String filename)
>     at ProjetoFCT.Form1.ConvPdfError3(String dest, String[] e) in C:\Users\user\Documents\Projeto\ProjetoA\Form1.cs:line 5253

### Código

```cs
        public void ConvTiffToPdf(string dest, string[] e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Length; i++)
            {
                int pages = 0;
                string output = dest + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e[i]) + ".pdf";
                iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create));
                writer.CompressionLevel = PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;
                writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7;

                string folder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "temporario\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e[i]);
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

                bool @continue = true;
                while (@continue == true)
                {
                    MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings
                    {
                        Compression = ImageMagick.CompressionMethod.LZW,
                        Format = MagickFormat.Tiff,
                        FrameIndex = pages
                    };
                    try
                    {
                        using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(e[i], settings))
                        {
                            string file = folder + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e[i]) + "- Página " + (pages + 1) + ".tif";
                            image.Quality = 75;
                            image.Format = MagickFormat.Tiff;
                            image.Write(file, MagickFormat.Tiff);

                            iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(file); //o erro é aqui
                            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(img.ScaledWidth, img.ScaledHeight);
                            document.SetPageSize(size);
                            document.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                            document.Open();
                            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                            img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                            img.SetDpi(300, 300);
                            cb.AddImage(img);
                            document.NewPage();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (ex is MagickException)
                        {
                            document.Close();
                            Invoke(new Action(() => { succed = 1; pbar.PerformStep(); caseSwitch = 6; }));
                            @continue = false;
                        }
                        else if(ex is System.ObjectDisposedException)
                        {
                            document.Close();
                            Invoke(new Action(() => { succed = 1; pbar.PerformStep(); caseSwitch = 6; }));
                            @continue = false;
                        }
                        else if(ex is System.ArgumentException)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                        }
                        else
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    }
                    pages++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Alguém me podia ajudar a descobrir o que está errado no meu código? 
Obrigada desde já.

Comment: qual versão do itext você está usando?

Comment: @LucasMiranda Eu tenho PDF com versões 1.3 e o iText versão 5 não estava a ler essas versões, então fui procurar a versão 4.1.6

Comment: O suporte de tiff no iText vai ter sempre problemas porque o formato tiff é essencialmente um saco para uma coleção de formatos de imagem. Se está a usar o Magick para conversões a melhor hipótese e guardar a imagem como PNG e não como tiff. Assim vai sempre funcionar.

Comment: @PauloSoares bem visto, mas a biblioteca PdfSharp faz o que preciso sem dar erro alguem, de qualquer maneira vou experimentar a guardar como PNG.

Comment: @PauloSoares se guardar como PNG funcionou sem algum problema. Obrigada.

Comment: Recomendaria você abandonar o tiff, por que você precisa trabalhar com essa extensão?

Comment: @LeandeoAngelo eu preciso de trabalhar com ela pois estou a fazer um estágio numa empresa que digitaliza documentos então o formato TIFF tem uma qualidade excelente e sendo que é Tagged é perfeito para organizar documentos.

Answer (score 2):

Eu tentei usar o PdfSharp e o ItextSharp.

Para coisas simples você precisa escrever muito código sendo que deveria isto estar encapsulado facilitando a sua vida.

Eu sugiro usar a biblioteca [IronPDF](https://ironpdf.com/docs/) que tem uma boa documentação e muito mais fácil de usar

Comment: Muito obrigada, já não estou a trabalhar nesse assunto mas pelo que vi, essa biblioteca parece ser uma opção muito interessante.